# CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported & CGContextDrawImage: invalid context

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, cgcontext, cgimage

I am using the following code to resize images. It works great with *all my other* images resizes... *except* with one that throws the following error.

What am I missing???

Note: `bitmap` returns null here for some reason, but it doesnt return null for other images. I dont get it why

One of the main differences that I notice from other images is that with this particular images (the one that errors). it enters the if statement

```
if (bitmapInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone) {
        bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
// I've also tried (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast with no different results
        }
```

Could there be the error?

This method is the method that calls the image resize.

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString  *jpgPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pictureName];
    [self _deleteFileAtAppPath:jpgPath];
    [imgData writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

    UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    thumb = [imageResize imageWithImage:thumb scaledToSizeWithSameAspectRatio:CGSizeMake(88, 88)];
```

**The error**

```
 ov  2 16:31:50 jonathan5s-iPhone[5114] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 16 bits/pixel; 1-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast; 475 bytes/row.
    2013-11-02 16:31:50.632[5114:60b] Bytes per row: 475
    Nov  2 16:31:50 jonathan5s-iPhone[5114] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
    Nov  2 16:31:50 jonathan5s-iPhone[5114] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. T
```

**The problematic method**

```
+ (UIImage*) imageWithImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage scaledToSizeWithSameAspectRatio:(CGSize)targetSize {
    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;
    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(00.0,0.0);


    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {
        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
            scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
        }
        else {
            scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width
        }

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image
        if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
        }
        else if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = [sourceImage CGImage];
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

    if (bitmapInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone) {
        bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
    }

    CGContextRef bitmap;

    if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {

        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetWidth, targetHeight, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

    } else {

        bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetHeight, targetWidth, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

    }


    // In the right or left cases, we need to switch scaledWidth and scaledHeight,
    // and also the thumbnail point
    if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(thumbnailPoint.y, thumbnailPoint.x);
        CGFloat oldScaledWidth = scaledWidth;
        scaledWidth = scaledHeight;
        scaledHeight = oldScaledWidth;

        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, M_PI_2); // + 90 degrees
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -targetHeight);

    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(thumbnailPoint.y, thumbnailPoint.x);
        CGFloat oldScaledWidth = scaledWidth;
        scaledWidth = scaledHeight;
        scaledHeight = oldScaledWidth;

        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI_2); // - 90 degrees
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -targetWidth, 0);

    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight);
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI); // - 180 degrees
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(thumbnailPoint.x, thumbnailPoint.y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error normaly indicates, that you are supplying a invalid size to CGBitmapContextCreate. You should check if the provided size arguments are not null, inf or nan.

Comment: I did and the images sizes are set properly